# String to datetime format installdate

Tags: .net, vb.net

how to convert string to date time in listview vb.net
20160928063905.000000+480
cant resolve with Parse

Win32_OperatingSystem
InstallDate

[image: Screenshot]

```
             Else
                    log.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Aqua
                    log.SubItems(1).Text = client.Machine_Name
                    log.SubItems(2).Text = client.Network_Information.IPAddress(0)
                    log.SubItems(3).Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
                    log.SubItems(4).Text = client.Network_Information.Name ' caption
                    log.SubItems(5).Text = client.Network_Information.InstallDate
                    log.SubItems(6).Text = client.Network_Information.ID
                    log.SubItems(7).Text = client.Network_Information.Manufacturer

                End If

        Next

        Dim item As New ListViewItem
        item.Text = EventLogListView.Items.Count + 1
        item.SubItems.Add(client.Machine_Name)
        item.SubItems.Add(client.Network_Information.IPAddress(0))
        item.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
        item.SubItems.Add(client.Network_Information.Name) 'captions
        item.SubItems.Add(client.Network_Information.InstallDate)
        item.SubItems.Add(client.Network_Information.ID.ToString)
        item.SubItems.Add(client.Network_Information.Manufacturer)


        item.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Aqua
        EventLogListView.Items.Add(item)
```

Comment: Is it so hard to read [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and write one or two complete sentences with the required information about your problem?

Comment: sorry , my problem is how to convert this string to 20160928063905.000000+480 this format yyyyMMdd in listview . sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Management` namespace in .NET includes a method for converting WMI encoded dates.

```
Dim installDT = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(wmiDateString)
```

Given a string of `"20160928063905.000000+480"` the result on my system is:

> Sep 27, 2016 17:39:05.000

Ripping up the string data results in a different value:

> Sep 28, 2016 06:39:05.000

The reason it is wrong is because the offset info is discarded in the first step:

```
dateStr.Substring(0, dateStr.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal)
```

Comment: followed this format but i still got SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this to change the format of your date before setting the text in your view :

```
Public Function GetDateFromWin32Date(dateStr As String) As String
        Dim newDateStr = dateStr.Substring(0, dateStr.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        Dim newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(newDateStr, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Return newDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") 'Use the format you'd like to display
End Function
```

Or in a single line :

```
log.SubItems(5).Text = DateTime.ParseExact(client.Network_Information.InstallDate.Substring(0, client.Network_Information.InstallDate.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal)), "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

And use it like this :

```
log.SubItems(5).Text = GetDateFromWin32Date(client.Network_Information.InstallDate)
...
item.SubItems.Add(GetDateFromWin32Date(client.Network_Information.InstallDate))
```